# minimize(cost) operation takes a lot of time

Tags: lstm, tensorflow

I have the following bit of code to compute the cost for an LSTM in tensorflow. When I execute the code, the optimizer step takes a lot of time to go through, ~25 minutes.

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y_class))
optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=lr).minimize(cost)
```

Why does this happen? Is this dependent on the sizes of my weights, biases, number of hidden layers in my LSTM?
I'm training the network on GTX 840M

Comment: what is your learning rate and mode of initialization of the weights and biases and the type of activation function?

Comment: I'm using `truncated_normal_initializer` for weights and `constant_initializer` for biases. The learning rate is 0.001

Answer (score 0):

It is quite normal that **RNN** is slower in GPU. According to the answer given here (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/19220/choosing-between-cpu-and-gpu-for-training-a-neural-network) sometimes its worse than the CPU depending on your GPU model.

RNN training time depends on the number of weight parameters (that depends on the number of inputs and hidden units). Therefore, if possible you can try to reduce those numbers.

Moreover, as suggested by this answer ([How to speedup rnn training speed of tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096896/how-to-speedup-rnn-training-speed-of-tensorflow)) you can,

1. Train with different batch sizes.
2. Use sampled softmax instead of regular softmax.

Furthermore, you can read this article (http://svail.github.io/rnn_perf/) from Baidu on **Optimizing RNN performance**, which gives u good understanding.

Hope this helps.